# Visual studio Tools available for standalone download?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

For doing code coverage using visual studio tools, are they available for download separately? I don't need the visual studio IDE for development, I need only the tools to instrument the dlls and capture code coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [How to: Install the Stand-Alone Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385771.aspx) and download it from [Analyzing profiling data from vsperfcmd](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/520313/Analyzing-profiling-data-from-vsperfcmd) which also cab be a good source for guidance.

I hope it support your question.